# Loading javascript file based on cookie using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I don't know why this code isn't working. This code should make sure that only one ad pop is presented in a user session. If I remove the two cookie lines then it works but not with the two cookie lines. Please help:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
var zflag_nid="1185";    
 var zflag_cid="3307";    
 var zflag_sid="823";   
 var zflag_width="1";    
 var zflag_height="1";   
 var zflag_sz="15";   

 if(!jQuery.cookie('myCookie1')) {
 jQuery.cookie('myCookie1','myValue');  
jQuery.getScript("http://d8.zedo.com/jsc/d8/fo.js",function(){ alert("Loaded");});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes in Firebug console it shows : jQuery.cookie is not a function. Looks like cookie plugin is not there in my Drupal default installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're including the jQuery cookie library before you call this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.cookie.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (!$.cookie("myCookie1")) {
                ...
            }
        </script>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

You can download the jQuery Cookie Plugin [here](https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js).

---

You *must* load the plugins before running that code. You can work around it by doing the following:

```
$(function() {
    if (!$.cookie("myCookie1")) {
        ...
    }
});
```

within your script block. This will make sure that the entire page is loaded before the code is run. However, you absolutely *must* include the plugin code *somewhere* in your page for this to work.

Comment: Should I wait for the plugins to load before I use cookie function? How can I ensure it then?

Comment: Yeah, you MUST wait for them to load. The cookie function doesn't exist before the plugin loads, so your code will fail. You might be able to get around it by doing the above, which I'm about to edit into the answer.

Comment: Can't I call this function from: $(document).ready ? Does ready() ensures that all linked js libraries are loaded too?

Comment: Yes, actually `$(function(){});` is just shorthand for `$.ready(function(){});` or `$(document).ready(function(){});`. It's a nice hack to shorten your code a lot :)

Comment: Does .ready() ensure that every content(images,.js files etc) of page is loaded?